# How to export only the python output not source code to ODT from emacs org-mode?

Tags: python, emacs, org-mode

I have python source code in emacs org-mode. I only want to export the output of python code to the ODT not the source code. How could I do that?

Here is my test code. When I do the export, only the source code in my ODT file.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :export result
  import pprint

  test_dict = {
      'a':1,
      'b':2,
      'c':3,
      "nested": {
          "n_a":1,
          "n_b":2,
          "n_c":3
      }
  }

  pprint.pprint(test_dict, indent=2, width=1)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: { 'a': 1,
:   'b': 2,
:   'c': 3,
:   'nested': { 'n_a': 1,
:               'n_b': 2,
:               'n_c': 3}}
```

Comment: Sweet, Python, emacs, orgmode, you're awesome!

Comment: @AaronHall Those tools are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set `:exports` header to `results`. [Here](http://orgmode.org/manual/exports.html#exports) is a link to the `org-mode` describing the header.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried it with the little piece of code in my edited post, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @enchanter, you have typo in your header vars, it should be `:export result` should be `:exports results`